# How to initiate "findInFiles" with VSCode extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to write an extension that will automatically select the word under the cursor, open the find in files dialog, and initiate a search with that selection.  So far, I've been able to get the extension to do everything except actually initiating the search.  I still have to press enter in the find in files dialog to actually do the search.  Here's the extension code I have so far:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.searchUnderCursor', () => {
        // Get the current editor
        let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (!editor) {
            console.log('No active editor!');
            return;
        }

        // Get word under cursor position
        let wordRange = editor.document.getWordRangeAtPosition(editor.selection.start);
        if (!wordRange) {
            console.log('No word under the cursor!');
            return;
        }

        // Select the word
        editor.selection = new vscode.Selection(wordRange.start, wordRange.end);

        // Initiate search
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles').then(() => {
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('default:type', {text: '\n'});
        });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

You can see I was trying to find a way to press enter in the find in files dialog to begin the search.  Of course, that doesn't work.  How can I get the functionality I'm going for here?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I figured it out.  Here's my solution:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.searchUnderCursor', () => {
        // Get the current editor
        let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (!editor) {
            console.log('No active editor!');
            return;
        }

        // Get word under cursor position
        let wordRange = editor.document.getWordRangeAtPosition(editor.selection.start);
        if (!wordRange) {
            console.log('No word under the cursor!');
            return;
        }

        // Get word text
        let wordText = editor.document.getText(wordRange);

        // Initiate search
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles', {
            query: wordText,
            triggerSearch: true,
            matchWholeWord: true,
            isCaseSensitive: true,
        });
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```

As it turns out, the `findInFiles` action has a number of useful args that it accepts: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9a987a1cd0d3413ffda4ed41268d9f9ee8b7565f/src/vs/workbench/contrib/search/browser/searchActions.ts#L163-L172

Comment: Related on `findInFiles` arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62251891/836330