# Search (Find in Files) keybinding can take arguments, workbench.view.search can't - other differences?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just want to know the difference between the `workbench.action.findInFiles` and `workbench.view.search`commands.  Both are used to access the Search across files panel.

My guess is that `workbench.action.findInFiles` is a newer version of `workbench.view.search` since I found  ['findInFiles' accepts parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821068/how-to-initiate-findinfiles-with-vscode-extension-api) and `view.search` doesn't.

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/cadabab73fef89fe0c4bfe23b5a33cd58e39ea9c/src/vs/workbench/services/search/common/search.ts#L24

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the title and question a bit to make the `findInFiles` args aspect easier for people to notiec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you hit on the only real difference.  They both have the same default keybinding but the `view` version does have a `context` arg of:

```
!searchViewletVisible
```

so it is really meant just to surface the search panel when it isn't visible.  But the `findInFiles` version will make the search panel visible too.  The only real difference is the ability to take arguments - which I think very few people know about.

As you point out, the `findInFiles` version can take arguments - which I didn't know before!!  So it is worth showing how.  Like this:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f",                    // whatever keybinding you wish
    "command": "workbench.action.findInFiles",
    "args": {

      "query": "${selectedText}",                  // variables don't work
      "replace": "that's $1 swell",
      "triggerSearch": true,                       // seems to be the default
      "filesToInclude": "${relativeFileDirname}",  // no variables
      "preserveCase": true,
      "useExcludeSettingsAndIgnoreFiles": false,
      "isRegex": true, 
      "isCaseSensitive": true,
      "matchWholeWord": true,
      "filesToExclude": "./*.css"
    }
  },
```

Full list of available args for `workbench.view.search`:

```
   "query": "",
   "regexp": "",
   "wholeWord": "",
   "caseSensitive": "",
   "includes": "",
   "excludes": "",
   "showIncludesExcludes": "",
   "useIgnores": "",
   "contextLines": 0,
   "triggerSearch": "",
   "focusResults":
```

---

The list of args above is being transitioned to those below (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/2fdc8c336c601e385fadfaa1802cdc67fea96241) to be consistent with the `findInFiles` command.  I assume the old args will work for some period of time but the new ones are in the Insiders' Build v1.51 so should be in Stable soon.

```
  "query": ""
  "isRegexp": true,
  "isCaseSensitive": false,
  "matchWholeWord": true,
  "filesToInclude": "",
  "filesToExclude": "",
  "showIncludesExcludes": false,
  "useExcludeSettingsAndIgnoreFiles": true,
  "contextLines": 2,
  "triggerSearch": true,
  "focusResults": true
```

---

If you have a commonly used search/replace this could be valuable and could be assigned to unique keybindings.

---

`workbench.view.search` can not take preset arguments, but `search.action.openNewEditor` can!  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207896/836330 for more.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173653 can be of interest  with VSCode 1.77 (March 2023).